# Initialising variables - why and what are the risks?

Tags: c++, variables

Having recently got feedback from Code Review stating the impropriety of non-initialized variables, my class variable initialization now seems very ugly:

```
class MyClass 
{
  private:
    int variable_one;
    int variable_two;
    int variable_three;
    MyClass():variable_one(0),variable_two(0),variable_three(0){};
    //...
};
```

Previously, I wouldn't define my variables until they are needed:

```
class MyClass 
{
  private:
    int variable_one;
    void MyFunction(int x)
    {
       variable_one = x;
    }
};
```

Why is my second example frowned upon? What are the risks involved by bot initializing variables?

Comment: Other methods may need to use the member variables and their is no guarantee of the calling order.  Better safe than sorry.

Comment: You can get garbage values out because you didn't set sane values when you constructed the class variable.  If there's no way for the user to see garbage, then it doesn't matter.  Your member variables are private; in the outline class, there's no way for anything outside the class to gain access to them.  It is possible that you are OK, but it seems unlikely.  You have no way of knowing whether the values have been set in the outline shown.  And not knowing the state is a paramount crime in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The risk with leaving variables uninitialized is that you might read them before they've been set up. That can lead to extremely hard-to-diagnose bugs and erratic behavior. You can also initialize them to sentinel values to make it easier to detect when they haven't been set up.

As a note, since C++11 (what's now supported by most compilers), you can just do this:

```
class MyClass 
{
  private:
    int variable_one = 0;
    int variable_two = 0;
    int variable_three = 0;

};
```

Now there's little code overhead and it makes clear that they get default values unless you specifically set them to something else.

Answer (score 2):

It is frowned upon because someone, someday is going to use your class and assume that internal state has been setup during initialization.  You are perhaps worried about initialization not needed and wasting time?  Instead, depending on how many various and assorted methods you have, you will be repeating the initialization code in every one of them, until you forget in just one of them, but it works fine because you ran in debug mode so all memory is cleared.  Then a month later, someone compiles in release and all the sudden they think that their code is broken because you didn't initialize your code in a central location.

RAII - Resource Allocation Is Initialization whenever possible.  When they create an instance of your class, make sure it is initialized.

Answer (score 2):

The answers provided so far are all correct, but no one mentioned there's a more general OO principle at work:  An object's methods transform it from one internally consistent state to another.  It should never be possible to use an object where it does something silly (unless it's a silly object).

For example, if an object has an array and a count of currently active elements in the array, it should never be true that there are active elements when count is zero.  The method that updates the array also updates the count, keeping the state *consistent* with itself.  The momentary inconsistency -- after the element is added and before the count is updated -- is not visible to the user of the object.

In your example, `MyClass` gets off on the wrong foot by creating a nondeterministic initial state.  Whatever relationship the member variables have to each other, their values are determined by compiler happenstance.  The more it's used, the probability that that's what you want approaches zero.

Answer (score 1):

The first method you've specified is called as initializer list, and it's the only way to initialize when you've const or reference data members in your class.

If you don't initialize your data members that are C++ objects, it will still be initialized to a default value by calling the corresponding constructor, and then the same exercise will be repeated when you try to initialize it at a later time (like how you're doing it inside a function, when you deem it to be necessary).

Comment: @user4581301, thank you. That sentence was supposed to be with the "when you have C++ objects as data members" sentence. I've re-worded it now and I hope it clears that up a bit.